# Overriding XMLHttpRequest's send function

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code that overrides XMLHttpRequest's send function.

```
var sendOrig = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    var self = this;

    setTimeout(function() {

        // Do something.

        self.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {

                // Do something else.

            }
        });

        sendOrig.apply(self, args);

    }, 0);
}
```

Do the event listeners pile up in this case or do they get garbage collected? And if not, how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

With every call of XHR.send() it will create new function as the event listener. But if you need a closure inside the handler (i.e. you access the self variable) this is the only way.

When you use this, you should make sure to clear every property that stores reference to XHR to make the Garbage Collection to correctly clear the handlers from memory.

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
//...
XHR.send(...);
//...
XHR = null; //not needed anymore - make sure GC can remove its handlers
```

Comment: The reason I'm overriding XMLHttpRequest is because I want to do something every time something is sent to the server, be it via jQuery or some other library calling XMLHttpRequest's send function directly. How would I achieve that with your code?

Comment: If you want to do something before/after an AJAX request is send or response is recieved, you have the right code in your question. My code was only to explain how you should use the XHR after you change it. If you use a library or framework (jQuery, ExtJS, etc.) they should be already able to use it correctly and there should be no problem.

Comment: Anyway, if you use a framework, you should look into its documentation for better way to achive this instead of messing with vanilla JS. For example jQuery has lots of AJAX events you can use: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ and ExtJs as well: http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.Ajax.html#events

Comment: I'm using libraries that use XMLHttpRequest directly so e.g. ajaxStart is not an option. Also your snippet does not help me because libraries handle XMLHttpRequests however they handle it. I was asking is there is a way (if it's even necessary at the first place) to deal with event listeners at this level (when overriding).

Comment: Developer asks 'Do I really need an event listener for what I want to do?' but a Pro developer asks 'Is there a suitable event for what I want to do?'. So the answer is 'yes, your code with the event listener is correct and is the best way you can use.'